# google storage signed url public read

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to create a signed URL for a public image
Is it possible to set the permission level on the URL or do I need to set it after the file is uploaded?

I tried to do it by passing some headers but I'm not sure on the correct way to do it.

```
opts := &storage.SignedURLOptions{
    GoogleAccessID: googleAccessID,
    PrivateKey:     data,
    Method:         "PUT",
    Expires:        time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 1),
    ContentType:    r.MimeType,
    Headers:        []string{"x-goog-acl"},
or maybe Headers:        []string{"x-goog-acl:public-read"},

}
```

Then the client need to set the header as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoever uses a signed URL acts with the permissions of the entity that signed the URL. Say you create service account A and use A's private key to sign the URL. When an end user tries to fetch a resource using that URL, GCS will check whether service account A has read access.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it when you create a new bucket writer.  You can set the headers and create an ACLRule.  I do this in an application I host on Google App Engine using the "google.golang.org/cloud/storage" package.  Hope this helps.

```
wc := bucket.Object(filename).NewWriter(ctx)
wc.ContentType = contentType
wc.CacheControl = "public, max-age=86400"
wc.ObjectAttrs.ACL = append(wc.ObjectAttrs.ACL, storage.ACLRule{Role: storage.RoleReader, Entity: storage.AllUsers})
```

Comment: this is after the file is uploaded into the bucket ,
Not on the time of the signed URL creation ?

Comment: This example shows you how to set the permissions when you are saving the file.  If you need to update the permissions after it has been saved you would use func (o *ObjectHandle) Update(ctx context.Context, attrs ObjectAttrs) to give it new permissions.  Based on your question I was under the impression the file was already public, so a Signed URL would not be needed since that is for restricted files that you want to share temporarily.